# Meaning of a number grid

Tags: gamma-function

The following note contains several math symbols like the $\Gamma$-functions:
[image]

In the background there is also a grid of numbers and there are some curved lines in there. Does someone know what there meaning is? Unfortunately I do not know too much about math, but I am almost sure that they should have a meaning. I was thinking around, but I did not found anything.

Thank you very much

Comment: This is described [here](http://currencies.wikia.com/wiki/Swiss_10_franc_banknote) as the seventh series banknote.

Comment: Thanks for the link:-)